# Can I use two SI prefexes

Tags: soft-question, si-units

Is it ok to say $145\,{\rm k\,MPa}$ for $145\, {\rm GPa}$. We are so used to comparing stresses in ${\rm MPa}$ that I want to keep things relative to this unit. So would it be a no-no to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately for you the authority says no.

> Compound prefix symbols, that is, prefix symbols formed by the juxtaposition of two or more prefix symbols, are not permitted. This rule also applies to compound prefix names.

<sup>[*Source*](http://www.bipm.org/en/si/si_brochure/chapter3/prefixes.html)</sup>

However, you might use $145\times10^3\text{ MPa}$.

Answer (score 2):

You will sometimes see, e.g., MMF printed on a capacitor for micro-micro-farads. You may also hear people refer to a nanometer as a millimicron. But this is all nonstandard, and today these usages would mark you as someone who hadn't crawled out from under a rock since 1955.

Comment: Lol, There is a reason I program in `FORTRAN`.